# Install nvcc on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use pytorch on GCP (Google Cloud Platform). The codebase requires nvcc on top of the regular CUDA.

I've tried several approaches but none of them has worked so far.

1) Deployed a template by NVIDIA (https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/containers/nvidia:pytorch). The template has cuda configured, but no nvcc. It suggests to run `apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` to install nvcc, which indeed works for nvcc installation but breaks the entire cuda.

2) Follow instructions to install nvidia stuff from scratch, e.g. https://medium.com/@jayden.chua/quick-install-cuda-on-google-cloud-compute-6c85447f86a1. Not worked either:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda : Depends: cuda-10-1 (>= 10.1.243) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Has anybody successfully installed CUDA + nvcc on GCP before?

Thanks and best wishes

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you make a backup of your google cloud instance, first.

Then, try to uninstall the currently installed cuda, nvidia packages, by invoking:

```
apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia-cuda-*"
apt-get --purge remove "*cublas*"
apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia*"
apt-get --purge remove "*cuda*"
apt-get autoremove
```

Then, remove the folders here:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/cuda-*/
rm -rf /var/cuda-repo-*/
```

Depending on your operating system name and version you might check out available [NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit installers](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive).
If you want to install the latest `CUDA Toolkit 10.1 update2 version 10.1.243` for `Linux Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64`, you can use:

```
# CUDA Toolkit 10.1 update2 https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-update2
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin
mv cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/10.1/Prod/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-1-local-10.1.243-418.87.00_1.0-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-1-local-10.1.243-418.87.00_1.0-1_amd64.deb
apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-10-1-local-10.1.243-418.87.00/7fa2af80.pub
apt-get update
apt-get -y install cuda=10.1.243-1
rm -f "cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-1-local-10.1.243-418.87.00_1.0-1_amd64.deb"
apt autoremove
```

Finally, verify the installation using these commands:

```
nvcc --version
```

You should see an output like this:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```